# How to call the most valued coins in coingecko?

Tags: react-native, coingecko

I'm trying to make API calls on coingecko API on my project using react native. I've did some calls and it's working fine. But there is one thing I want to do: show, let's say, top 10 most or top 5 valued coins in 24 hours or 7 days. I don't know if there is one way to do it using API call, I tested something like on Postman:

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=price_change_percentage_24h&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en
```

but it didn't give me the result I wanted, since the coins are not ordered based on price change valuation. Is there some way to do it via API calls or I will have to use web automation and scraping?